# What is the template file for node add/edit page?

Tags: theming, nodes, 8

I need to add extra CSS styles for a set of fields in the node add page for the *jobs* content type, but I don't know what template file should I use. I enabled Twig debugging, and I tried the following options.

- page--node--add--jobs.html.twig, but it shows all regions
- `hook_theme()`, but the custom template is not getting applied

My code for `hook_theme()` is the following.

```
 function custom_module_theme() {
  //  dpm("node:".drupal_get_path('module', 'comp_jobs'));  
  return [
    'node-jobs-form' => [
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'jobs',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'comp_jobs') . '/templates',
    ],
  ];
}
```

What template file should I use, and how do I tell Drupal to use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template for the node add form is **node-edit-form.html.twig**. But adding attributes to form fields is not an easy task in twig. You probably are able to do this more efficient in a form alter hook.